# Flutter change audio frequency

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically I'm using the plugin `sound_stream` which it's very nice to record/play or stream the mic audio.

I'm trying to do this stream listen to frequency between **2.35Hz and 2.5Hz**.

How it would be possible to archive this?

I learned mainly Java but I'm trying to do both platforms that's why I'm using Flutter. So help/tips are very appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Got any solution?

Comment: No, it's very hard to find help on customizations on flutter, most people only do design and interface since it's basic....